# docx4j excel xlsx insert image on android platform

Tags: android, xml, xlsx, docx4j

i am new to docx4j ,i have previously used apache poi to insert multiple images into excel xlsx on my Android app,due to Huge and heavy library size imposed by poi, i am looking for alternative. docx4j image inserting seemed to be much more complex than i thought after looking at the  examples sample,is there a much better alternative in jaxbxml part of coding to insert image into excel  xlsx file? i have no idea what are those prcocedure spell out on addimage with coding or xml are all about,totally stranger to me,docx4j documentation about this image creation portion is poor,anyone able to provide some guidance,Aspose cell for docx4j is not opensource either